# How do I add a function on a specific post category?

Tags: categories, customization, theme-twenty-eleven

I am using theme Twenty Eleven and am trying to add a vote up script in the content.php which only displays on a certain category.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that in multiple ways .. 
For example you can  do a conditional in the PHP itself with a wp built in function :

```
if ( in_category( 'my-category' ) {
 //Do something
}
```

or for example, if the script is a javascript you could load the script in a conditional way , so it would not load where it is not needed - it will save also some processing time (change the condition to what you want).

```
    function dl_add_js_conditional() {

        if (!is_admin()) { //if is not admin - will load only on front-end
            wp_register_script('myscript_name_js', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/myscript_file.js', array('jquery'));
            wp_enqueue_script('myscript_name_js');
        }
if (is_home()) { //will load only on home
            wp_register_script('myscript_name_js', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/js/myscript_file.js', array('jquery'));
            wp_enqueue_script('myscript_name_js');
        }
    }
    add_action('init', 'dl_add_js_conditional');
```

Or , you can also do the detection / condition in the script itself (you did not specify what script you use, Jquery, Javascript or other)

Comment: Could this be done in functions.php ?